# How can I read, change and save an Excelfile in R and keep the color-coding using the openxlsx package?

Tags: r, excel, openxlsx

I do have an Excel-file with specific color-coding, which I want to read in R, change (based on a comparison with another R-object) and save it with the initial color-coding of the cells that have not changed. Unfortunately, I'm restricted to the openxlsx-package as the xlsx-package is not working due to java - R - Problems. For proof-of-concept purposes I used the following Excel-file:

[image]

Any help would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

A solution with `openxlsx2`. You were a little vague how the other object looks like, therefore I choose a similar sized data frame that was changed in cell `C6`:

```r
library(openxlsx2)

# create the example file
tmp <- temp_xlsx()

df <- data.frame(
  x = 1:5,
  y = c(2, 3, 5, 5, 6),
  z = c(3, rep(4, 4))
)

wb <- wb_workbook()$
  add_worksheet()$
  add_data(x = df)$
  add_fill(dims = "B4", color = wb_color("yellow"))$
  add_fill(dims = "C6", color = wb_color("yellow"))$
  save(tmp)

rm(wb)

####################
wb <- wb_load(tmp)

# read a special data frame with attributes
xl <- wb_data(wb)

# compare against a modified object
df$z[5] <- 5
sel <- xl == df
# get the cells region of the data
dims <- attr(xl, "dims")
dims <- dims[-1, ][!sel]

message("this cell(s) changed: ", paste0(dims, collapse = ", "))
#> this cell(s) changed: C6

# remove the cell
wb$clean_sheet(dims = dims)

# overwrite the entire region
wb$add_data(x = df)

if (interactive()) wb$open()

# wb$save(tmp)
```

Comment: The clean part require looping if multiple cells have changed.

Comment: The example works perfectly. However, the two dataframes I'm comparing have 104*627 cells (65208 cells). Thus, I need a way to store the color-information for my first df, compare it with the second one and then apply it again to the first one. It would also already be fine if the colored cells just stay as they are, even though the cell information has changed. How would you do that?

Comment: You can overwrite the data region with `wb$add_data()` as shown in the example above. Cleaning the cell style will take a moment if you loop over a few cells, but unless you are paid by the minute, it should be fine.